# How to stop the rerender of a calendar component when displaying a modal component on top of it in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, modal-dialog, rerender, daypilot

My main page contains a calendar where you can create events. To create an event I display a modal, which causes unintentional rerender of the calendar. So this causes displaying current week in the calendar and not the week where I wanted to create the event. I think the problem is caused by using `showModal` state in the calendar component which triggers the rerender after displaying the modal. However, I'm not quite sure how to fix it. I'd be grateful for some tips.

Calendar:

```
export default function CalendarComponent({onTimeRangeSelected}) {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const getCalendar = () => {
    return calendarRef.current.control;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getEvents = async() => {
        return await pb.collection('events').getFullList();
    }
    getEvents().then(data => {
      const mappedEvents = data.map(event => ({
        id: event.id,
        start: new Date(event.start),
        end: new Date(event.end)
      }));
      setEvents(mappedEvents);
    })
  }, [])

  const createEvent = async(args) => {
    const dp = getCalendar();
    const event = await pb.collection('events').create({
      start: args.start,
      end: args.end
    });

    dp.events.add({
      id: event.id,
      start: args.start,
      end: args.end,
    });
  }

  const handleTimeRangeSelected = async (args) => {
    const dp = getCalendar();
    setShowModal(!showModal);
    createEvent(args);
  }

return (
      <div style={styles.wrap}>
        <div style={styles.left}>
          <DayPilotNavigator
            selectMode={"Week"}
            weekStarts = {1}
            showMonths={2}
            skipMonths={2}
            startDate={date}
            selectionDay={date}
            onTimeRangeSelected={ args => {
              getCalendar().update({
                startDate: args.day
              });
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div style={styles.main}>
          <DayPilotCalendar
            events={allEvents}
            ref={calendarRef}
            viewType = {"Week"}
            weekStarts = {1}
            headerDateFormat = {'dddd d.M.yyyy'}
            durationBarVisible = {false}
            timeRangeSelectedHandling = {"Hold"}
            onTimeRangeSelected={handleTimeRangeSelected}
          />
        </div>
        {showModal && <CreateEvent showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal}></CreateEvent>}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Modal:

```
export default function CreateEvent({showModal, setShowModal}) {
    const [lesson, setLesson] = useState('');
    const [lessons, setLessons] = useState([]);

    const toggleModal = () => {
        setShowModal(!showModal);
    }

    if (showModal) {
        document.body.classList.add('active-modal');
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('active-modal');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const getLessons = async() => {
            return await pb.collection('lessons').getFullList();
        }
        getLessons().then(data => {
            setLessons(data); 
        })
    }, [])

    const handleLessonChange = (e) => {
        setLesson(e.target.value);
    }

    console.log(lessons);
    return(
        <>
            {(
                <div className="modal">
                    <div className="overlay" onClick={toggleModal}></div>
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <input type="button" className="close-modal" onClick={toggleModal} value={"X"}></input>
                        <label htmlFor="lesson">Předmět:</label>
                        <select id="lesson" value={lesson} onChange={handleLessonChange}>
                        {lessons.map((lesson) => {
                            return(
                                <option value={lesson.name}>{lesson.name}</option>
                            )
                        })}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```